# Azure App Service - Set-AzWebApp : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am trying to run Set-AzWebApp command to set web application properties

```
Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $settings -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appServiceName
```

$settings is a Hashtable.
I get this message back with no additional details

> Set-AzWebApp : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved: As it turns out I had a space that crept into my keyname within the $settings hashtable. This cause Azure app service to throw a 409 Conflict.

Comment: You can add the comment to the answer part.

Comment: Tl;Dr the problem here is typically a typo, check your command, especially the case of the setting

Comment: I got the same error while trying to create an web app using `New-AzWebApp` cmdlet. For me it worked on retry. I didn't make any changes in the script for retry. Not sure why it came in first place.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: As it turns out I had a space that crept into my keyname within the $settings hashtable. This cause Azure app service to throw a 409 Conflict

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue when creating an Azure App Service Plan using Azure Powershell.

When I run the command below:

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroup' -Name 'MyServicePlan' -Location 'northeurope' -Linux -Tier 'Premium V2' -NumberofWorkers 2 -WorkerSize Medium
```

I get the error:

> New-AzAppServicePlan: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that I was specifying the **Tier** as `'Premium V2'` instead of `'PremiumV2'`. That is there should be no space between the word `Premium` and `V2`. They should be together.

So this worked for me after then:

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroup' -Name 'MyServicePlan' -Location 'northeurope' -Linux -Tier 'PremiumV2' -NumberofWorkers 2 -WorkerSize Medium
```